# Connecting Raspberry Pi to old found TFT display

Tags: pi-3, power, usb-power, wiring, lcd

I have an old car DVD player sitting around that has a fairly decent secondary TFT LCD screen (hannstar 721h440b19-a1) that I thought I could use with my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

I opened up the unit, and the issue I'm running into is that the control board receives the video, power and audio signal all through a single USB connection. I was curious if there was a simple way to get the display to work with my raspberry pi with the least amount of hacking to the control board. Is there a way to pass video through USB on the Pi? Or could I desolder the USB connection and run wiring for power, video, and audio separately?

[image: hannstar 721h440b19-a1 TFT LCD Display]
[image: Control board details]

Comment: If not impossible, making a random LCD screen from a random device work with a raspberry pi would probably need so much hacking and work that buying a new LCD would be a far better and easier option.

Comment: looks like some french guy was looking at the same thing https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=142551 run that through google translate, see if it helps you at all

Comment: Just ran the above link through Google translate, and the result of the discussion was that it would be much cheaper and less time-intensive to buy a new display.